# libGDX: SocketTimeoutException with android

Tags: java, android, sockets, libgdx, cross-platform

I am currently working with libgdx. I want to connect via websockets to a Java Server Application that is already running.
When I start the desktop application everythins works fine, but the android app won't connect.

I receive the following LogCat output:

> 03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2370
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405): Process: com.myProject.android, PID: 27405
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error making a socket connection to 192.168.1.100:4444
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at com.badlogic.gdx.net.NetJavaSocketImpl.(NetJavaSocketImpl.java:51)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidNet.newClientSocket(AndroidNet.java:70)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at com.myProject.ServerConnector.connect(ServerConnector.java:53)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at com.myProject.application.XDKVisualizer.create(XDKVisualizer.java:61)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1512)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405): Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.100 (port 4444) after 2147483647ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:225)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:165)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:116)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:838)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at com.badlogic.gdx.net.NetJavaSocketImpl.(NetJavaSocketImpl.java:46)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   ... 6 more
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:212)
>   03-13 16:05:21.508: E/AndroidRuntime(27405):   ... 12 more

Here are the Code snippets of the server and client applications:
Server:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(mPort);
    try {
        while (listening) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            Thread sender = new SensorDataSender(clientSocket, numClients++);
            sender.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        serverSocket.close();
    }
```

Client:

```
    SocketHints hints = new SocketHints();
    hints.connectTimeout = CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
    hints.socketTimeout = SOCKET_TIMEOUT;
    Socket socket = Gdx.net
            .newClientSocket(Protocol.TCP, mIp, mPort, hints);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));

    new EventProcessor(in).start();
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? I tried the kyronet alternative already and received the same timeout.

BR,
Flo